# understanding async and await in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I am trying to understand why promise is not resolved when I am using async and await keywords. Below is the code that I have

```
var a = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

async function fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch(a);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}
console.log(fetchData());
```

fetchData function should return actual datas but it always returns a promise object. What am I doing wrong?

I am expect the following output `[{userId: 1, name: 'ss'}]`after invoking `fetchData()`

Comment: `async` functions always return promises, so your statement that "fetchData function should return actual datas" is wrong. You need to obtain the promise's value either by using `then` with a callback or by calling `fetchData` from within an `async` function and `await`ing it.

Comment: then what is `await` keyword is for?

Comment: It allows you to not have to worry about promises _inside the function_. It's why you're able to use `response` on the second line of the function rather than having to do `fetch(a).then(response => response.json())`

Comment: `console.log(await fetchData())`

Comment: @JonasW. It will throw a syntax error.

Comment: Cause it has to be inside of an `async function`.

Comment: What happens when you execute an asynchronous function? Nothing, it just promises something at a later point in time which is represented by the Promise object you get.

Comment: The async is used with a function to makes it into an asynchronous function. The await keyword is used to invoke an asynchronous function synchronously. The await keyword holds the JS engine execution until promise is resolved.

We should use async & await only when we want the result immediately. Maybe the result is being returned from the function or getting used in the next line.

[Follow this blog, It is very well written in simple word][1]


  [1]: https://www.ui-dev.in/2021/02/async-await-in-javascript-when-to-use.html

Answer (score 2):

The way async works is that it returns a promise. So what you can do is:

```
fetchData().then(data => console.log({data}))
```

And you'll print out your data!

Also, you don't need that line:

```
const data = await response.json();
```

because the `.json()` method is synchronous, and thus there's no need to wait for a promise to be resolved.

So a simpler way to do it would be:

```
var a = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

async function fetchData() {
    const response = await fetch(a);
    data = response.json();
    // do stuff with data, synchronously
    return data;
}
```

---

so you want to write code without callbacks, but then what you need is to use `fetchData()` in an async context, so here's how you can do that:

```
async function asyncPrint(aPromise) {
    console.log(await aPromise);
}

asyncPrint(fetchData);
```

and if you're evil, you could do:

```
console.asyncLog = asyncPrint;
```

so you can run:

```
console.asyncLog(fetchData());
```

Comment: I don't want to do it like `fetchData().then(data => console.log({data}))` I want something like `fetchData()` [{'userId': 1, 'name': 'ss'}]  How do i do that?

Comment: @sajankumarvijayan Then you're out of luck. If you want to perform asynchronous actions (and making an HTTP request is an asynchronous action), you need to understand how to work with asynchronous code.

Comment: @sajankumarvijayan I updated my answer to show you how. Basically, you cannot `await` in a non `async` context, but you can create a function that will handle that for you.